# "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive"

Tags: iis, http-headers, content-security-policy

I have my CSP set to `default-src 'self'` and 20+ errors saying `Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive`. Do I have to add every single hash into my CSP header? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: could you share the error snapshot from the console tab here?

Comment: you could try to add the http response header in iis with Name: Content-security-Policy and value: default-src 'self'; at the site level

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to move all CSS to a separate file. If it is in a style attribute just adding the hash won't make a difference as it will still fail.